# Oracle ADF Check box losing state

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-adf

I'm using JDev 12c.

I'm trying to implement some check boxes to work as radio buttons like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TTZqa/

But i can't make it work.

I have a form - t2 - that contains three rows in which every row has one check box. When the user select the check box it should be checked and if another check box is already checked it should become unchecked.

It should only be possible to have one row checked and exactly one row must be checked upon submission.

I have the following listener on my checkboxes:

```
<af:clientListener type="click" method="sayHello"/>
```

and my JS function look like this:

```
function sayHello(event) {
          event.cancel();
          var source = event.getSource();

          var chk1 = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('t2:0:sbc1');
          var chk2 = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('t2:1:sbc1');
          var chk3 = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('t2:2:sbc1');

          if (source == chk1) {
              chk1.setValue(true);
              chk2.setValue(false);
              chk3.setValue(false);
          }
          else if (source == chk2) {
              chk1.setValue(false);
              chk2.setValue(true);
              chk3.setValue(false);
          }
          else if (source == chk3) {
              chk3.setValue(true);
              chk2.setValue(false);
              chk1.setValue(false);
          }
      }
```

I know that the function is called when either of the check boxes is clicked but all boxes remains unchecked. I can see that the check mark flashes briefly but it doesn't stay.

If I call an empty javascript function the user can click all three check boxes and the check mark stays in the boxes but they are not mutually exclusive and it works as i'd expect.

But when i write the function like this:

```
function sayHello(event) {
          event.cancel();
          var source = event.getSource();
          var chk1 = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('t2:0:sbc1');
```

}

The check mark disappears immediately.

I've tried to delete the 'event.cancel(); but it doesn't make any difference.

I can even substitute the component i find with an input field in the same form and wite text to it. the text appears in the input field but the check mark dissapears immediately from the check box.

I've studied:

http://technology.amis.nl/2013/05/07/adf-client-side-architecture-select-all/

what am i doing wrong here?

thanks

Kim

EDIT:

I've created the following very simple page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
<af:document title="untitled2.jsf" id="d1">
    <af:messages id="m1"/>
    <af:resource type="javascript">      
      function sayHello(event) {
          event.cancel();
          var source = event.getSource();
          var chk1 = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('sbc1');
          var chk2 = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('sbc2');
          var chk3 = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('sbc3');
          if (source == chk1) {
              chk1.setValue(true);
              chk2.setValue(false);
              chk3.setValue(false);
          }
          else if (source == chk2) {
              chk2.setValue(true);
              chk1.setValue(false);
              chk3.setValue(false);
          }
          else if (source == chk3) {
              chk3.setValue(true);
              chk2.setValue(false);
              chk1.setValue(false);
          }        
      }
    </af:resource>
    <af:form id="f1">
        <af:panelGridLayout id="pgl1">
            <af:gridRow height="100%" id="gr1">
                <af:gridCell width="100%" halign="stretch" valign="stretch" id="gc1">
                    <!-- Content -->
                    <af:selectBooleanCheckbox label="Label1" id="sbc1" clientComponent="true">
                        <af:clientListener type="click" method="sayHello"/>
                    </af:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <af:selectBooleanCheckbox label="Label1" id="sbc2" clientComponent="true">
                        <af:clientListener type="click" method="sayHello"/>
                    </af:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <af:selectBooleanCheckbox label="Label1" id="sbc3" clientComponent="true">
                        <af:clientListener type="click" method="sayHello"/>
                    </af:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </af:gridCell>
            </af:gridRow>
        </af:panelGridLayout>
    </af:form>
</af:document>
```

and i see exactly the same strange behavior.....i can't seem to select the check box. the check mark simply disappear.

Any input? I'm stuck here.

/
Kim

Comment: Did you try to alert the values that you receive.
for instance did you try to make alert(source.getValue()); to see what do you receive.
Also did you make sure that chk1, chk2 & chk3 are actually created successfully.
I believe your comparison should be based on Id, not the equality
source.getId() == chk1.getId()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the javascript function with something like this:

```
<af:resource type="javascript">      
  function sayHello(event) {
      var source = event.getSource();
      var chk1 = source.findComponent('sbc1');
      var chk2 = source.findComponent('sbc2');
      var chk3 = source.findComponent('sbc3');
      if (source.getId() == chk1.getId()) {
          chk1.setValue(true);
          chk2.setValue(false);
          chk3.setValue(false);
      }
      else if (source.getId() == chk2.getId()) {
          chk2.setValue(true);
          chk1.setValue(false);
          chk3.setValue(false);
      }
      else if (source.getId() == chk3.getId()) {
          chk3.setValue(true);
          chk2.setValue(false);
          chk1.setValue(false);
      }        
      event.cancel();
  }
</af:resource>
```